# How to filter the aggregation results in Kibana (elastic search)?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-6

I want to filter the elastic search aggregation results in **Kibana** (v6.2). For example, I want to show only sum of hours those that are more than 100 (like **HAVING** command in **SQL**). I know that we can filter the results in **filter** section over other fields, but I don't know how to apply the filter on aggregation functions. I tried to use **post_filter** in filter section in Kibana, but it didn't work. 
Any ideas? [image]

Comment: Hello, I am having the same problem. Did you ever figure out how to "organize" the results by the aggregation (sort results by the count* function)?

Comment: Hello, No. I have not checked it out recently, but by that time there was such features in Kibana

Answer (score 1):

You can augment aggregation query within advanced field

It will be added to request as shown on picture

[image: Kibana advanced aggregation fields]

Another question is what to put into this field. You can check [script values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html) for sum aggregation

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? What is test? I want to filter the "sum of fields".